# How can I add to an index of a 2 dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Can anyone tell me how to add a new item to an index of a 2 dimensional ArrayList. The links [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884816/how-can-i-add-an-integer-to-an-element-in-a-2-dimensional-arraylist) do not resolve my problem.

My code to add was the following:

```
wq.get(donsay).set(wq.get(donsay).size(), sil5);
```

which causes the following exception =>

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray/chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray.MainActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3
```

Thank you all in advance...

Comment: Can you share more code?  It's tough to tell what you're trying to accomplish without knowing if `wq` is a map or list or ?  also what type are `donsay` and `sil5`?

Comment: Hello, quite right.. I assumed that everyone knows what I am doing. 'donsay' is an integer and is derived from the first syllables  of the phrase 'loop number' in my language. sil5 is a String. I am trying to add sil5(String) to index 'donsay'(integer) at wq's (a string ArrayList) donsay index length (which is  a number). It is supposed to extend this index by one element considering index 2 => 0,1 but length 2 => 0,1,2 Pls let me know if everything is clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set() method of ArrayList expects an index less than size.
Use add() method instead:

```
wq.get(donsay).add(wq.get(donsay).size(), sil5);
```

Comment: I think this is the answer I am looking for. I'll check in a few mintes and let you know... Regards and thank you

Comment: In this case, no need to calculate the index, you can just do `wq.get(donsay).add(sil5)`